# Coldfusion String remove everything after last comma

Tags: string, coldfusion

I have some dynamic data that gives me something like this:

```
123,151425,15641,12
```

I need to remove everything after the very last comma so it displays:

```
123,151425,15641
```

I have this code, but it only removes the last comma. I need to remove the comma *and* everything after it.

```
<cfset NewString = ReReplace(OldString, '(.*),', '\1')>
<cfoutput>
   #NewString#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You need to search for it at the end of the string. Something like this would probably work `ReReplace(OldString, "(,[^,]*)$", "")`, but I do not see a big advantage over list functions in this case.

Comment: BTW, +1 for a [good first question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that has all the right ingredients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
<cfif ListLen(OldString) GT 1>
  <cfset NewString = ListDeleteAt(OldString,ListLen(OldString))>
</cfif>
```

If you want some more flexibility in how many elements to chop off the end, [ListDeleteRight](http://cflib.org/udf/ListDeleteRight) from [CFLib.org](http://cflib.org/) would be useful.

```
<cfscript>
/**
 * Deletes the n rightmost elements from the specified list.
 * Modified by RCamden
 * 
 * @param list      The list to modify. 
 * @param numElements      The number of elements to delete. 
 * @param delimiter      The delimiter to use. Defaults to a comma. 
 * @return Returns a string. 
 * @author Shaun Ambrose (shaun.ambrose@arcorsys.com) 
 * @version 1, April 24, 2002 
 */
function ListDeleteRight(list, numElements) {
    var i=0;
    var delimiter=",";

    if (Arraylen(arguments) gt 2) {
        delimiter=arguments[3];
    }

    if (numElements gt ListLen(list, delimiter)) return "";

    for (i=1; i lte numElements; i=i+1) {
        list=listDeleteAt(list, listLen(list, delimiter), delimiter);
    }
    return list;
}
</cfscript>
```

Usage:

```
ListDeleteRight(list, numElements [, delimiter])
```

Example:

```
<cfset NewString = ListDeleteRight(OldString,1)>
```

Comment: thank you for you help just using the list len part was enough, thanks again

Comment: I am guessing you missed [Adrian's comment about using ListLen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876024/coldfusion-string-remove-everything-after-last-comma#comment40495936_25876109) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Use `ListDeleteAt()`, using `ListLen()` to get the position of the last element.

```
ListDeleteAt(list, position [, delimiters ])
```

Comment: If the input does not contain any commas it returns an empty string. Also for an empty string it throws an error 
"Invalid list index 0"

Comment: Why does that matter? The OP noted that the string has commas in it.

Comment: Add a conditional check for listLen() > 1.

Answer (score -1):

Another Solution:

Here i am leveraging java string functions `lastIndexOf` to return last comma index and `substring` function to extract from the beginning of the string to the position of last comma.

```
 <cffunction name="stripAfter" returntype="String" output="false">
   <cfargument name="input" type="string" required="true">
   <cfargument name="delimiter" type="string" required="false" default=",">
   <cfset lastCommaIndex = input.lastIndexOf(",")>
    <cfif lastCommaIndex EQ -1>
        <cfreturn input>
    </cfif>
   <cfreturn input.substring(0, lastCommaIndex)>
 </cffunction>

 <cfoutput>
    #stripAfter(OldString)#
 </cfoutput><br/>
```

Comment: How very Rube Goldberg-ish. `listDeleteAt()` works just fine for the problem at hand.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to dip into java for this, but .. I probably would not down vote it as the basic logic is the same as with the list function approach. Side note, be sure to properly scope all function variables ie `arguments,local,...`

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @DanBracuk - How is it more complicated? Ignoring the fact he chose to wrap it up a UDF, since that is a good practice for reuse, the amount of logic is the same. Get the position. If greater than 0/1, grab a substring. There are no savings with the list function approach. It is no less "complicated".

Comment: It's more complicated because it's a reinvention of existing coldfusion functions.

Comment: No, it is just a different way of doing it, and most likely is similar to what CF is doing beneath the hood anyway. Again, I do not think it is needed, but it is hardly more complicated that using list functions.